# How to Allow White space between words in MVC Regular Expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Below is My Code

```
[RegularExpression("[A-Za-z]*", ErrorMessage = "Use Alphabets Only")]
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add space in the end or space`+` if you want to allow 2 or more spaces:

```
[RegularExpression("([A-Za-z]| *)*", ErrorMessage = "Use Alphabets Only")]
```

Comment: Dude its  Only Accepting Space at last. i want space between two words

Comment: Also the space should be Optional since some data will contain only one word while others may contain more than one word. So i need space when there is more than one Word.